# MariaDB aborted connections and lagging system

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

So I have this server that has the following settings under `my.cnf`:

```ini
[mysqld]
event_scheduler = off
max_connections = 1200
wait_timeout = 60
#connect_timeout = 30
interactive_timeout = 60
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 134217728
max_allowed_packet = 32M
#open_files_limit = 80000
innodb_file_per_table = 1
```

The server gives the following errors:

```
Aborted connection 344 to db:****(Got Timeout)
Aborted connection 344 to db:****(Got Timeout)
```

It lags with a 32 GB Ram and 16 CPU cores.

Any assistance on this will be appreciated.

I have tried increasing the wait timeout to 180 seconds but I still have the lag issue.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Please post the schema, sample data and the queries you are running.

Comment: Are you getting the error message on the server or client side?
And after what time? It looks like a client side message, so if it still appears after 60s even though you raised wait_timeout this is probably happening in some interactive client (e.g. a GUI or the `mysql` command line client) which sets the "interactive" connection state flag, and so `interactive_timeout` instead of `wait_timeout` is used.

Comment: I am sorry guys I found a temporary solution. But to answer your question @hartmut-holzgraefe . The error is on server's logs. It is a database-intensive application with over 500k requests per day and 7GB data transfer. Some are therefore experiencing timeout. 

Side Question: Is it better to do virtualization in this case?